# VSTS/TFS GUI: Auto-switch repository per team view?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

Our company has been using Visual Studio Team Services for several months now. One thing that would be helpful for people who split time across teams would be for the Code tab to cause the selected repository be the one associated with that team.

With our current setup, we'll go from one team view to another, and the selected repository does not change.

Can this be accomplished with the out-of-the-box VSTS/TFS configuration? We're open to extensions as well, but that would not be the first choice.

Answer (score 1):

No, we cannot achieve that. You have to navigate manually if you want to switch repository from one to another. It will not auto-switch, no such relationship between team and repository in TFS/VSTS.

As a workaround you can [add the repositories reflect each team to **Favorites**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/account-home-pages#favorites-open-items-youve-marked-as-favorites), then you can switch to the corresponding repository conveniently from **My Favorites** in the account hub.

Comment: i asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577455/how-to-silo-git-repos-for-teams-in-vsts and think this is a very obvious requirement. Is it something the team is considering?